# Creating a reusable function for loaders in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to find a way how to create a reusable function that prevents me from repeating the same loader code over and over again. An example can be seen below:

```
one = new THREE.Group();

var loader1 = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader1.crossOrigin = '';
loader1.load('',
    function (texture) {
        this.geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10);
        this.mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'white'});
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geo, this.mat);
        one.add(mesh)
    }
);


twp = new THREE.Group();

var loader2 = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader2.crossOrigin = '';
loader2.load('',
    function (texture) {
        this.geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10);
        this.mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'white'});
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geo, this.mat);
        two.add(mesh)
    }
);
```

**My attempt was as follows:**

```
example = new THREE.Group();

function reuse(obj) {   
    this.loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    this.loader.crossOrigin = '';
    this.loader.load('',
        function (texture) {
            this.geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10);
            this.mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:'white'});
            this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geo, this.mat);
            obj.name.add(mesh)
        }
    )
};
var test = new reuse({name: 'example'});
```

I also tried pushing the mesh in an array within the function:

arr.push(mesh);

arr.mesh[0].position.x
etc.

I also tried returning it.

What exactly is the best and working method to avoid such disaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when dealing with duplicate code the most common and easiest way is to create a simple function

example with your code:

```
function getTexturedCube(path){
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10);
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    //you dont have to put onLoad function in, 
    //the texture returned will automatically update when it is loaded
    var texture = loader.load(path);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:texture});
    return new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
}

var group = new THREE.Group();
var cube1 = getTexturedCube("/path/to/image");
var cube2 = getTexturedCube("/path/to/other/image");
group.add(cube1);
group.add(cube2);

var anotherGroup = new THREE.Group();
var cube3 = getTexturedCube("/path/to/yet/another/image")
anotherGroup.add(cube3);
```

you can also pass the function a reference to your group and make it push the object into it

```
function addTexturedCube(path, object){
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10);
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var texture = loader.load(path);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:texture});
    object.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material));
}

var group = new THREE.Group();
addTexturedCube("/path/to/image", group);
addTexturedCube("/path/to/other/image", group);
```

Comment: I find the second one more compact. So in this case there was no real use in creating a type of class using "this". A simple function is exactly equivalent and the way you did it absolutely makes sense.